# Vimeo video won't be responsive

Tags: mobile, responsive-design, vimeo

I can't seem to get the Vimeo video on this page to be responsive. I've tried lots of different code that's worked for other people, but not on this page. Can anyone help??? Here is the page: http://give.brighamandwomens.org/stories/entry/stepping-strong

Answer (score 1):

Currently you have `width: 550px` which is the reason why its not responsive. You need to add `width: 100%;` on the `.ss_video` class for it to adjust to screen size.